# How to extract compound words from a multiline string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, set

I have a text string from which I want to extract specific words (fruits) that may appear in it; the respective words are stored in a set. (Actually, the set is very large, but I tried to simplify the code). I achieved extracting single fruit words with this simple code:

```
# The text string.
text = """
My friend loves healthy food: Yesterday, he enjoyed 
an apple, a pine apple and a banana. But what he 
likes most, is a blueberry-orange cake.
"""

# Remove noisy punctuation and lowercase the text string.
prep_text = text.replace(",", "")
prep_text = prep_text.replace(".", "")
prep_text = prep_text.replace(":", "")
prep_text = prep_text.lower()

# The word set.
fruits = {"apple", "banana", "orange", "blueberry",
          "pine apple"}

# Extracting single fruits.
extracted_fruits = []
for word in prep_text.split():
    if word in fruits:
        extracted_fruits.append(word) 

print(extracted_fruits)

# Out: ['apple', 'apple', 'banana']

# Missing: 'pine apple', 'blueberry-orange'
# False: the second 'apple'
```

But if the text string contains a fruit **compound** separated by a space (here: "pine apple"), it is not extracted (or rather, just "apple" is extracted from it, even though I don't want this occurrence of "apple" because it's part of the compound). I know this is because I used `split()` on `prep_text`. Neither extracted is the **hyphenated** combination "blueberry-orange", which I want to get as well. Other hyphenated words that don't include fruits should not be extracted, though.

If I could use a variable `fruit` for each item in the `fruits` set, I would solve it with f-strings like:

```
fruit =  # How can I get a single fruit element and similarly all fruit elements from 'fruits'?
hyphenated_fruit = f"{fruit}-{fruit}"
for word in prep_text.split():
    if word == hyphenated_fruit:
        extracted_fruits.append(word)
```

I can't use the actual strings "blueberry" and "orange" as variables though, because other fruits could also appear hyphenated in a different text string. Moreover, I don't want to just add "blueberry-orange" to the set - I'm searching for a way without changing the set.

Is there a way to add "pine apple" and "blueberry-orange" as well to the `extracted_fruits` list?

I appreciate any help and tips. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into (or are you aware of) regex matching?

Comment: @Ray Toal: A little, yes. But because I don't want to extract all hyphenated words but only those with fruits in it, I don't know how I could use regex in this matter...

Comment: You could extract all hyphenated words and then filter out the ones that aren't fruits.

Comment: The question how to extract compound fruits separated by space remains...

Answer (score 1):

The quickest (and dirtiest?) approach might be to use this regex:

```
(banana|orange|(pine\s*)?apple|blueberry)(-\s*(banana|orange|(pine\s*)?apple|blueberry))?
```

It will match `pineapple`, `pine apple`, `pine    apple`, and pine apple with newlines or tabs between `pine` and `apple`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQtDni/1/)

One disadvantage is, of course, that it matches things like `orange-orange` and there's repeated text in there. You can construct the regex programmatically to fix that, though.

It's just a start but may be good enough for your use case. You can grow it to add more capabilities for a bit, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For my actual use case, however, it is not very suitable because the set is - like I said - very large (1000 elements), so "hardcoding" the fruits in regex is rather impossible, unfortunately.